# Differentiating between server threads (user connections)

Tags: java, multithreading, client, client-server

I'm wondering what the best way to differentiate between server connections is. My client connection has their own thread, which I aim to put in a group with 2 other users (3 in total) kind of like a lobby.

I'm currently looking at ThreadGroup and trying to assign every 3 users to a thread group however I'm not sure this is even remotely correct, as I cannot see any clear way of then finding which users are in which thread group.

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be very helpful.

Comment: What is the goal for putting users (or other classes of threads) in a group?

Comment: Essentially they are finding players to play with, and the maximum is 3, so it would allow the server to keep track of points and the round of the game etc, for that specific group of users.

Comment: I wouldn't use a `ThreadGroup` for this Luke.  I'd you a collection of threads or a custom class that can store additional meta data.

Comment: Ok, that seems to make a bit more sense, I'll give this a go. Thanks.

Comment: I promoted my comment to an answer Luke.

Comment: I can back up @Gray on that.  If you want to group clients, put their socket-objects into some collection. Lock the collection so that new clints can be added and disconnected clients can be removed in a managed fashion.  Link it all up - put the collection instance in each client instance so that clients can get access to the collection and get lists of their fellow group members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a `ThreadGroup` for the purposes of classifications of threads.  A `ThreadGroup` allows threads to do operations and get information about a collection of threads.  I don't think you need this functionality.

I'd use one of the `Collection` classes to group your user or game threads together.  The `Collection` could be inside of the custom class which you use to store the game state.

If you need to find the games that need more members then I'd have a `Collection` of games that need members that you add and delete from as users login/out.